# MySQL prepared statement in Java not returning a value

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I have a web service method that executes a prepared statement against a MySQL database.  When I run this statement in MySQL I get a returned value:

```
SELECT first_name
  FROM lytthouse_airlines.passenger
 WHERE passenger_id = 1
```

;

but when I run this prepared statement in my java class, it doesn't work:

```
PreparedStatement getName = connection.prepareStatement(
   "SELECT first_name " +
   " FROM lytthouse_airlines.passenger " +
   " WHERE passenger_id = ? "
 );

getName.setInt(1, passengerId);
rs = getName.executeQuery();
returnValue = "After executing query";

if (rs.next()) 
{
   returnValue = "inside rs.next";
   returnValue = rs.getString("first_name");
}
```

When I test this what I get in the returnValue contains "After executing query"; which would imply that there is no ResultSet (rs) returned and therefore not getting into the if (rs.next()) logic.

Anyone have any clue what's wrong?

**New Content**

After Guo's response I changed the code a bit so I could see the value of passengerId.  When I run a Test of the web service I get this very interesting result.

```
Method parameter(s)

Type    Value
int     1
Method returned

java.lang.String : "After executing query, with a passengerId of 0"
```

I have double-checked and I am not changing the value of passengerId anywhere in the method before it gets to they query.

**Another new comment**

I think the problem has nothing to do with the prepared statement it seems to have to do with the method itself.  I change the very beginning of the method to look like this

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getPassengerName")
public String getPassengerName(@WebParam(name = "passengerId ") int passengerId)
{
   //MySQL elements
   Connection connection;
   ResultSet rs = null;

   String returnValue = "start method with passengerId having a value of: " + passengerId;
```

and when I run the test I get this:

```
getPassengerName Method invocation


Method parameter(s)

Type    Value
int     1
Method returned

java.lang.String : "start method with passengerId having a value of: 0"
```

I think this calls for a new question.  I will pose a new question now.  Thank you again for everyone who looked at this and provided feedback.  I sure do appreciate it.

Comment: Try to replace 'if (rs.next())' to while(rs.next()), then dump all records like in this example http://www.herongyang.com/JDBC/sqljdbc-jar-ResultSetMetaData.html

Comment: Add rs.beforeFirst() before your if. @Lytthouse

Comment: Is `passenger_id` an integer in the database?

Comment: Hi Alex, I did change to a while(rs.next()) to no avail. Still not getting into the loop (in this case) so still not getting the desired data from the table.

Answer (score 1):

I test the result in my localhost, and its result is right.
So I think you have not a record whose `passenger_id = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `rs.beforeFirst()` before your if.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I sure appreciate the response, but unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: Run SELECT first_name
  FROM lytthouse_airlines.passenger
 WHERE passenger_id = 1 on your mysql client and post the output.

Comment: As a new member of this forum, I cannot yet attach a picture.  I did however run that query. and the result is "Matthew".

Answer (score 0):

This just means `rs.next()` returns false. `System.err.println("error message")` or just actually using a debugger (you should actually use a debugger) may better help you. So you just don't have a record with passenger_id 1. Did you verify this in your SQL editor directly?